# Set operations on Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

How can one perform set operations on a `HashMap`, such as `Collections.addAll()`?

Comment: The values to be added would be an array of Strings specifically.

Comment: ...Then what would the keys be?  Can you go into greater detail about what you are specifically trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Strings would be the keys. There would be no values (at least in practice).  I only want the O(1) lookup of a map.

Comment: what does a value-less map give you that a set does not?

Comment: A map gives O(1) lookup.

Comment: There's nothing inherent in maps that provides O(1) lookup.  In fact a tree map has O(log(n)) lookup.  It's the hashing that provides O(1) lookup.  if you want O(1) lookup and Set operations, you should use a HashSet.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use this map? More detail is needed.

Comment: A `HashSet` has the same performance characteristics for lookup as a `HashMap`. In fact, `HashSet` is implemented in terms of `HashMap` under the covers. Just use a `HashSet` instead of trying to use a `HashMap` with no values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you comments to the questions asked I think what you really need is a Set not a Map.

Try

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.addAll(...);
```

Use `mySet.contains("someString");` for quick determination if a value exists. It should be equivalent of what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Through for instance [`Map.putAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29).

You may also be able to do set-operations directly on the set of map entries which you can get hold of through [`Map.entrySet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

From [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29):

> *Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. **The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.***

Comment: Neither `entrySet` nor `keySet` support `add` or `addAll` however, as the documentation you cite goes on to say.

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
hashMap.putAll(map);
```

From [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29):

> Copies all of the mappings from the
>   specified map to this map These
>   mappings will replace any mappings
>   that this map had for any of the keys
>   currently in the specified map.

Answer (score 1):

You can do operations like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Set<String> set = map.keySet();
for(String s: set);
set.retainAll(set2); // keeps the keys in set2
set.removeAll(set3); // removes the keys in set3
set.remove(s);
```

You can also turn a Map in a Set. There is no ConcurrentHashSet but you can do

```
Set<String> set = Collections.setFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());
```